# Как найти направление от одной точки до другой в Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Я разрабатываю игру на pygame, и мне нужно чтобы враги шли в сторону игрока. Пытался использовать math.atan2 чтобы найти направление

```
def find_direction(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    dif_x,dif_y = x1-x2,y1-y2
    return math.atan2(dif_y,dif_x)
```

Но это не работает. Как реализовать эту функцию? (у меня готова функция передвижения объекта в его направлении в градусах)

Comment: atan2 угол в радианах возвращает, вы его в градусы переводите?

Comment: Нет, а как это сделать? И правильно ли я использую atan2?

Comment: градусы = радианы / пи * 180. Теоретически (если смотреть по документации) - правильно, но я с ней не работал, поэтому гарантировать не могу, нужно запускать и проверять (после добавления перевода в градусы, конечно).

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы перевести радианы в градусы можно использовать функцию `degrees` библиотеки math

```
import math

def find_direction(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    dif_x,dif_y = x1-x2,y1-y2
    return math.degrees(math.atan2(dif_y,dif_x))
```